# Catch mouse button pressed signal from qComboBox popup menu

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots, popupmenu, qcombobox

I have made multi-select `QComboBox`. Items are checkable (every item have check box and text value). CheckBox is checked only when user click on it. What I want is to catch signal when user click on text value so I can set check box next to it checked. How to do that?

[image]

This is how I set model to combo box:

```
areas = ["Area one", "Area two", "Area three", "Area four"]
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 1)# 5 rows, 1 col

firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("---- Select area(s) ----")
firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
firstItem.setSelectable(False)
model.setItem(0, 0, firstItem)

for i,area in enumerate(areas):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(area)
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
    model.setItem(i+1, 0, item)

self.ui.comboBox.setModel(model)        
self.ui.comboBox.installEventFilter(self)
```

I've added event filter to block wheel event,so `firstItem`'s text is always shown as "chosen"

```
def eventFilter(self,target,event):
    if target == self.ui.comboBox:
        if(event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.Wheel):
            #wheel event is blocked here
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: By modifying the eventFilter and installing in to the main application to see every single event fired. There doesn't seem to be any events sent at all when interacting with the comboBox :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to connect a handler to the [pressed signal](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#pressed) of the combo's [view](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#view):

```
    self.ui.comboBox.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
    ...

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.ui.comboBox.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works (when I click on text value: checkBox is changed) but now I can't check/uncheck checkBox directly. Any idea why?

Comment: @Aleksandar. Use the `pressed` signal instead (I've updated my answer).

Comment: that's it.. I've also removed `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` flag so if user click directly on check box, only `handleItemPressed` will change state of check box. Also I've added `if not index.row() == 0:` in `handleItemPressed` to disable user to check `firstItem`, and now everything works as I want