# Capture actions from checkable combobox

Tags: python, pyqt, qtoolbutton

Inspired by the following thread: [PyQt: How to set Combobox Items be Checkable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775095/pyqt-how-to-set-combobox-items-be-checkable)
I was able to create a simple checkable "combobox" by using a QToolButton and adding checkable items to it using addAction.
See simple code example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
class Ui_Dialog(object):
   def setupUi(self, Dialog):
       Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
       Dialog.resize(198, 157)
       self.toolButton = QtGui.QToolButton(Dialog)
       self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 71, 19))
       self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
       self.toolButton.setText("MyButton")
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.toolMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.ui.toolButton)
        for i in range(3):
            action = self.toolMenu.addAction("Category " + str(i))
            action.setCheckable(True)
        self.ui.toolButton.setMenu(self.toolMenu)
        self.ui.toolButton.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyDialog()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But how can I capture which of the QToolButton actions (i.e. *Category 1* and/or *Category 2/3*) that has been checked in my dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can define your [`QActionGroup`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qactiongroup.html) to collect all of your `action`s, then `connect` the signal `triggered` to callback method, this way:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.toolMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.ui.toolButton)
        group = QtGui.QActionGroup(self.toolMenu)
        for i in range(3):
            action = self.toolMenu.addAction("Category %d" % i)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            action.setActionGroup(group)
            action.setData(i)
        self.ui.toolButton.setMenu(self.toolMenu)
        self.ui.toolButton.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        group.triggered.connect(self.test)

    def test(self, act):
        print 'Action' , act.data().toInt()[0]
```

Here in `test()` method, reading the `data` of each `action` returns a [`QVariant`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvariant.html#toInt) which you need to convert it back to `int` using `toInt` method returning `(int, bool)` tuple, thus `[0]`

Comment: Note that with the second version of [PyQt API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt_qvariant.html) (by default in Python 3), `QVariant` are automatically converted to python types.

Comment: This solution made the toolButton to only accept one action, so I can't make a multiselection of actions.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to loop through the actions of the menu.There's no convenience function to do this, but every widget has a method `findChildren`. To get a list of all the children of type `QAction`, you do:

```
 self.toolMenu.findChildren(QtGui.QAction)
```

For every action, we can use `QAction.isChecked()` to get a boolean.

Full example:

```
def whatIsChecked(self):
    for action in self.toolMenu.findChildren(QtGui.QAction):
        if action.isChecked():
            print(action.text(),"is checked")
        else:
            print(action.text(),"is not checked")
```