# PyQt: How to keep ComboBox open while selecting items

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Following the solution provided at the following link (which works nicely):

[PyQt: How to set Combobox Items be Checkable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775095/pyqt-how-to-set-combobox-items-be-checkable)

How can I keep ComboBox open while selecting items?
Currently, with the offered solution, on each select, the list collapses...

Comment: i think you'd be better of showing a pop-up that contains the items as check boxes

Comment: how would you collapse the list if you keep it open after each select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a revision of the linked solution that keeps the list open. The list can be closed by clicking outside of it, or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class CheckableComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self._changed = False

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        self._changed = True

    def hidePopup(self):
        if not self._changed:
            super(CheckableComboBox, self).hidePopup()
        self._changed = False

    def itemChecked(self, index):
        item = self.model().item(index, self.modelColumn())
        return item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked

    def setItemChecked(self, index, checked=True):
        item = self.model().item(index, self.modelColumn())
        if checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.combo = CheckableComboBox(self)
        for index in range(6):
            self.combo.addItem('Item %d' % index)
            self.combo.setItemChecked(index, False)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The following solution does not work on mac.
Please see the following video:
https://youtu.be/JjANkg2ndgw

Comment: @Nir. I can't test on a mac, so I'm not able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps better use a `QListWidget`/`QListView` instead. The checkable flags should work with that, too, if you set them with each `QListWidgetItem` or in your custom model (e. g. using a `QStandardItemModel`).

Reason why I advise against using a combo box: That widget isn't meant to stay open for multiple selection; you would violate user expectations and should expect usability problems ("How can I close that selection? It doesn't work like the others!").