# How to create an interactive text menu in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not sure what to call it. I want to know how to make one of those menus where you use the arrow keys to highlight your options and press enter to accept it.

Comment: What interface do you want the arrows keys to interact with menu in? Do you want a separate Graphical User Interface (GUI) Window like `Qt` or will the menu appear in a Windows DOS Command Prompt as dropdown text menus? Also, what Operating System, Windows, MacOS, Linux, etc?

Answer (score 4):

The questioner acknowledged being unsure how to clearly state what they're after (*I know the feeling!*) and it *is* a little while after the question was posted, but in light of their comment suggesting they were after ***text***, I believe something like [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit), which is used to provide text-based autocomplete in a number of Python projects, may offer a solution.

There is documentation [here](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/pages/asking_for_input.html#autocompletion) which has this example of using a WordCompleter:

```py
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter

html_completer = WordCompleter(['<html>', '<body>', '<head>', '<title>'])
text = prompt('Enter HTML: ', completer=html_completer)
print('You said: %s' % text)
```

That produces output like this:

[image]

The example above is still relatively like a ComboBox merely rendered in text, but there are ways to produce other styles of menu as shown in the gallery [here](http://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/gallery.html#ptpython-a-python-repl).

If that isn't sufficient then another option is looking into something that wraps [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), like https://bitbucket.org/npcole/npyscreen or http://urwid.org/ .

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question including the examples you provided is curses. This package is very much dependent on the underlying operating system. So if platform independence is key then you will get issues. There is for example a Windows port UniCurses but your implementation has to handle this switch if  necessary.

There are also tools built on top of curses. Four example Urwid.

I personally have some experience with curses and if you have Linux as the underlying system this can be fun if your requirements are robust and simple. Like your menu requirement. I have to say though that the learning curve is pretty steep.

Hope this helps.  But given the broad question thus is the only level of detail to provide at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `Combobox`.
Here is a short example based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775095/pyqt-how-to-set-combobox-items-be-checkable) and [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class CheckableComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()
        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.toolbutton = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.toolbutton.setText('Select Categories ')

        self.toolmenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        for i in range(3):
            action = self.toolmenu.addAction("Category " + str(i))
            action.setCheckable(True)
        self.toolbutton.setMenu(self.toolmenu)
        self.toolbutton.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(self.toolbutton)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    combo = Dialog_01()
    combo.show()
    combo.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When I try to run that code, it gives me an import error, saying there's no PyQt4 module.

Comment: Oh, and I looked up Combobox and that's not what I'm looking for. It should be all text, like you can run in a terminal. Kinda like how you choose options while installing Linux without a GUI.

Comment: First, if you have an import error you probably don't have the required libraries - so try "pip install <MISSING_LIB>. Second - try to be more specific and provide more information regarding your needs.

Comment: Pip can't find PyQt4, but maybe I'm trying the wrong thing. Second - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWG0v.png. I think that picture kinda gives an example. You highlight your selection with the arrow keys and press enter to select it.