# PyQt5, Qt Designer. Multiple QCheckBoxes in a drop-down list

Tags: drop-down-menu, pyqt5, qt-designer, qscrollarea

Can you tell me how to implement a drop-down list with multiple QCheckBoxes? [Like here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsJdb.gif)

I tried to use QScrollArea, but it needs to use Q*BoxLayout which creates too much extra space. [if use QScrollArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACS7X.gif)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt: How to set Combobox Items be Checkable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775095/pyqt-how-to-set-combobox-items-be-checkable)

Comment: @mahkitah Almost. I need the drop-down menu not to close immediately when making a selection