# PyQt4 checkboxes are not showing (but clickable) on Mac OS, on Windows it works fine

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm creating a GUI with PyQt4 for my bachelor thesis. I have a QComboBox, where every item is a checkbox. Here is my code:

somewhere in the constructor:

```
self.multi = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
self.multi.setEnabled(True)
self.multi.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
```

and here I fill the QComboBox with my checkboxes:

```
def fillMultiCombo(self):
    # len(self.featureNames) rows, 1 column
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(self.featureNames), 1)

    firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("feature(s)")
    firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
    firstItem.setSelectable(False)
    model.setItem(0, 0, firstItem)

    for i,query in enumerate(self.featureNames):
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(query)
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setData(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        model.setItem(i+1, 0, item)

    self.multi.setModel(model)
```

Just to say in advance: I think it's not a code issue, but I provided some code to make it clearer.
The problem now is: On Windows 7 (on 2 different machines) it all works fine. But on my tutor's machine (Macbook Pro, I don't know which OS sorry), the checkboxes are not showing (but no error or warning printed), BUT when you click it, the checkbox is checked. So it's like the checkbox is there and functions, but it is invisible.

So is this a bug, machine dependent or some other issue. Because all other things work on her machine totally smooth.

Comment: Is that the *actual* code that has the issue? I can't test it myself, but does adding `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` to the flags make a difference on osx? It seems to be asking for trouble to leave it out, and I don't see a good reason for doing so (despite the comments made on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21208359/984421)).

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Anyway what about a minimal, working example showing the error?

Comment: @Trilarion: I'll try and send it to my tutor. Problem is I can't check the solutions, because I don't have a Mac ;) I'll edit my question as soon as possible.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I tried and it didn't solve the problem. This is very, very strange :S

Comment: @ekhumoro and Trilarion: I've found the problem and the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I've finally found the problem. Here is the important code snippet:

```
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

#   Available styles (depending on the OS) for my ThinkPad:
#   Windows
#   WindowsXP
#   WindowsVista
#   Motif
#   CDE
#   Plastique
#   Cleanlooks
    # makes the split bar visible
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
```

So before I set the style for my application, Qt chose the most appropriate style depending on the plattform resp. OS. So the default style Qt chose for my machine worked and the checkboxes are normally shown. The default style Qt chose for the application on the machine from my tutor was not the same. In fact if I change from 'Plastique' to 'Cleanlooks' my checkboxes also disappear.